# How to select date range from a asp.net calendar control in a single calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

i am having a doubt that how can i select date range in asp.net calendar control
for example i will give start date and end date so that all the dates in between those dates should get selected.

Can any one help me in this please

Comment: Are you checking the SelectedDates property? Or are you wanting to know how to select multiple dates?

Comment: i will give date nov1 and nov7, then in calendar it should select nov1 to nov7

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [SelectedDatesCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.selecteddatescollection?view=netframework-4.8)

This is an example from the link...

```
// Iterate through the current month and add all Wednesdays to the 
// SelectedDates collection of the Calendar control.
for (int i = 1; i <= System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(current_year, current_month); i++)
{
   DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(current_year, current_month, i);
   if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
   {
     DisplayCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(currentDate);
   }
}
```

Comment: I have a small doubt sir, i am providing this for all the months in the same calendar control. if it is possible can you please help me out i am struggling from last night  @chriscatignani

Comment: When you add dates to the SelectedDates (Collection) you are adding them to a single calendar control....(waives white flag.)